# Printing Backwards and on same line

Tags: java, string, printing, numbers, stringbuilder

The goal of this program is to take input from a file and strip off each digit and convert it to text. We cant use string manipulation. 
For example
1: one
21:two one
150: one five zero

But mine looks like this    1:one 21:one one two 150: one one two zero five one

Well I figure out a lot of it but mines printing all on one line and backwards can you guide me in the right path

Thank you

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("translate.txt"));
  while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
      int number = scanner.nextInt();
       System.out.println(number + ": " +NumberTanslatorTrial.tanslate(number) );
    // System.out.println(number + ": " + NumberTranslator.translate(number));

  }


}
```

New Class

```
 public class NumberTanslatorTrial {

final private static String[] txt = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
    "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
static int tempNumber;
static String finalString;
static int tempNumber1;
public static StringBuilder num = new StringBuilder();

public static String tanslate(int number) {
    while (number > 9) {
        tempNumber = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        num.append(txt[tempNumber]);
        num.append(" ");
        finalString = num.toString();
    }
    if (number <= 9) {
        num.append(txt[number]);
        num.append(" ");
        finalString = num.toString();
    }
    return finalString;

}
```

}

Comment: Alright so add a num.append("\n") on num <=9 and its giving each output a new line but still wrong.

Comment: Instead of mathematics, you could just convert to a string and analyze each character...

Comment: @aliteralmind we can't do string manipulation

Answer (score 1):

The problem with doing %10 then / 10 is that it looks at the LEAST significant digit first.

for example, for input = 167, you have these steps:

1. digit = 167 % 10 = 7
2. input = 167 / 10 = 16
3. digit = 16 % 10 = 6
4. input = 16 /10 = 1
5. digit = 1 % 10 = 1
6. input = 1 / 10 = 0

So you see, you end up with 7 first, 6, second, and 1 third.

The easiest way to fix this is to use a stack.

```
if (number == 0) { 
    return "Zero"; 
} // special case
if (number < 0) { // Handle negatives.
   num.append("Negative");
   number = -number;
}
List<Integer> stack = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (number != 0) {
  stack.add(number % 10);
  number /= 10;
}
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
   int digit = stack.remove(stack.size() - 1); // Pop off the stack.
   if (num.length() != 0) { // Add space if necessary.
      num.append(' ');
   }
   num.append(txt[digit]);
}
return num.toString();
```

Comment: your's also does this 1:one 2: two one 41: four one two one

Comment: Ah, you need to clear the "num" between calls. It actually should be a local variable in translate() instead of a static one.

Comment: i saw that once I wrote the comment it has to be cleared so needs to be declared in the method thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
  public static String tanslate(int number) {
        StringBuilder num = new StringBuilder(); // if global var should be reinialized with every call to remove old data
        while (number > 0) {  
            int tempNumber = number % 10;  // no need to define the global var
            number = number / 10;
            num.insert(0, " "); //insert at index 0, replace with "\n" for new line
            num.insert(0, txt[tempNumber]);  //insert at index 0
        }
        return num.toString(); // no need to define the global var finalString
   }
```